# How to encapsulate data when having a manager class

Tags: c++, oop

---

Hi,

I have a class called Manager that manages (creates, deletes, modifies, etc) multiple instances of a class called Element.
The Element class is a very simple class (just a data container).

```
class Manager
{
public:
    void add_element(ElemKey key);
    const Element *get_element(ElemKey key);

private:
    container<Element> my_elements;
};
```

As you can see, I have a method that returns an Element to the user.
I'd like the user not to be able to change anything in the element, since this is the manager's job.

Also, I'd like to add a method to the Manager that gets an Element pointer and other parameters and modifies Element.

I could get the key to the element instead of getting a pointer, but for performance reasons I'd like to avoid the extra lookup.
Something like this:

```
void something_happend_to_elem_do_something(Element *elem, ...);
```

The problem with it is that the user got a const pointer and not a pointer, so either me or him need to const_cast it.
If I do it, the user may not understand what going on, because even that he gave a const *, the method changed the object.
Besides, this seems to be a bad approach.

I thought of other methods to resolve this:
1. The Element could be changed to:

```
class Element {
public:
    int get_a();
private:
    int a;
};
```

And the Manager class can be friend of Element, so only he can change it.
I can now drop the const from Manager::get_element

1. The element could be changed to:

   class Element {
   public:
       virtual ~Element() {}
       virtual int get_a() = 0;
   };

Inside the manager cpp file another class will be created called ElementImpl that only it knows with the data in it, so only it can change it.
Like before, I can drop the const from Manager::get_element

There're drawbacks to each method.
None of them seem to be perfect design wise.
I think using only keys as parameters instead of pointers would be a better approach, but unfortunately I can't spare the extra micro seconds.

What to you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a Manager class might be questionable. Hence, having a Manager allowing only a subset of possible modifications to elements managed, you might return a Proxy:

```
class Proxy {
   public:
   Proxy(Element& e) : e(e) {}
   void modification() { e.modification(); } 
   private:
   Proxy(const Proxy&);
   Proxy& operator = (const Proxy&);
   Element& e;
};
```